# How can I connect an external camera to my phone and make it work like the built-in camera of the phone?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, camera, android-camera

I am testing the scan function, and currently, I can only manually take pictures of QR codes for testing. I am trying to use Raspberry Pi as a virtual camera to read video files and output to the phone. But I find it difficult to do this because I can't call the external camera like I call the built-in camera of the phone. Is there a way to solve this problem?